# Як правильно "плести" чи "в'язати" одяг?

Tags: вживання-слів, синоніми

**Як правильно сказати *"плести"* чи *"в'язати"* одяг? *"Плетений"* чи *"в'язаний"* одяг?**

Визначення із  СУМ-11:

> [В'язати](http://sum.in.ua/s/v.jazaty) **3.** Плести що-небудь спицями, гачком і т. ін.
>   *Чорнявий чоловік старі нерети понаправляв і почав в'язати новий* (Марко Вовчок, VI, 1956, 233); *В кутку біля настільної лампи бабуся
>   в'язала мені рукавицю* (Леонід Смілянський, Сашко, 1957, 21).
>
> [Плести](http://sum.in.ua/s/plesty) **1.** Перевиваючи пасма, волокна, нитки і т. ін.,
>   з'єднувати в одно ціле; виготовляти що-небудь виттям, переплітанням. 
>   *Плести косу; Плести панчоху.*

Я заплуталась в даних визначеннях, оскільки в першому з них присутне друге. ***В'язати означає плести?!*** Чи може це означати, що слова синоніми?

Якщо із визначення *"светр"* все зрозуміло:

> [Светр](http://sum.in.ua/s/svetr) в'язана тепла кофта без застібок з високим коміром, яку
>   одягають через голову.

Як бути з іншим одягом - сукня, спідниця, шарф, шапка та ін., правильно сказати *"плетена/ий"* чи *"в'язана/ий"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Згідно з Вашим визначенням, *[в'язати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=17156&page=576)* (у третьому значенні) є частковим випадком від *[плести](http://sum.in.ua/s/plesty)* (в першому):

> **В'ЯЗА́ТИ**, в'яжу́, в'я́жеш, *недок[онане]*. <…> *що і без прям[ого] дод[атка]*. Плести що-небудь спицями, гачком і т. ін. *Чорнявий чоловік старі нерети понаправляв і почав в'язати новий [нерет]* (Марко Вовчок); *Бабуся Одарка все в'язала свої панчохи* (В. Підмогильний); *В кутку біля настільної лампи бабуся в'язала мені рукавицю* (Л. Смілянський).

Тобто слово *в'язати* передбачає певну технологію (на яку словник натякає словами *спиці* й *гачок*), тоді як *плести* можна більшою кількістю способів. Наприклад, *косу* ми *плетемо* (*заплітаємо*, *розплітаємо* тощо), а не *в'яжемо* — це не підпадає під технологію в'язання (ми робимо це просто руками; [Leipzig Corpora Collection](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83) знаходить 718 «заплести» + 315 «заплітали» + 294 «розплітали» + 265 «заплітати» + 227 «заплетену» + 199 «розплела» + 194 «розплітати» + 175 «плести» + 145 «сплести» + 132 «розплітав» + 99 «розплітає» + 87 «розплітала» + 82 «розплітають» + 79 «заплели» зліва від словоформи «косу», але жодного разу чогось із коренем *-в'яз-*). Так само ми зазвичай *плетемо*, а не *в'яжемо* побутові предмети *з лози* (Тарас Щевченко: *«З лози колисочку плете // та плаче праведная мати, // колиску тую плетучи»*), *сіті* (Іван Франко: *«Старі діди, поважні, сивобороді, походжали коло хат, то дещо тешучи, то плетучи сіті на звіра та на рибу»*; 100 «плести» + 68 «плів» + 59 «плете» + 58 «плетучи» + 41 «плетуть» + 40 «плели» й жодного на *-в'яз-* у [корпусі](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D1%81%D1%96%D1%82%D1%96)), *вінки* (Петро Козланюк: *«З оцих дзвіночків дівчата плели віночки на голови»*; 3902 «плели» + 1681 «плетуть» + 744 «плести» + 251 «сплетені» + 223 «плела» + 124 «сплітали» + 115 «плете» + 113 «сплели» + 102 «сплести» й жодного на *-в'яз-* у [корпусі](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8)) тощо.

Тобто muffin у [вилученій відповіді](/a/4538) мав рацію, що «*в'язати* більш конкретизоване».

Також у *в'язати* є ще інші значення. Зокрема зав'язати можна вузол (і косу теж можна зав'язати вузлом, але це зовсім не те саме, що заплести). Але це, по-моєму, мало стосується контексту запитання.

Також принаймні частину з тих речей, які можна плести, але не можна в'язати, можна *[вити](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=11133&page=374)* (*[завивати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=27971&page=934)*; не в значенні «по-вовчи кричати», а в значенні «вплітати, робити завитки») — але різницю в значенні між цим словом (словами) і *плести*/*в'язати* не розглядав.

Answer (score 0):

На Вікіпедії є стаття "[В'язання](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%27%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F)", де слова "плетіння" та "в'язання" вживаються як синоніми. І спершу я подумав, що можливо в'яжеться лише гачком, однак знайшов такі слова:

> Плетіння гачком як один з різновидів декоративно-прикладного мистецтва
>   у нашій країні відоме з давніх давен і з кожним роком все поширюєтьсят
>   серед прихильників активного відпочинку.

Та й навіть згідно до СУМу, на який ви опираєтеся задаючи це питання, можна побачити, що ці слова справді можуть бути синонімами. Також знаходимо підтвердження цього припущення в [словнику синонімів](https://www.uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8).

А коли ми говоримо про одяг, то й справді все залежить від того яким способом його виготовили.

Comment: Думаю, що радше [_плести_ й _в'язати_ є гіперонімом і гіпонімом](/a/4889).